# BFS - TreeTraversal

Tags: ruby, data-structures, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

I have the following array of employees which I'm trying to traverse using BFS approach.

```
array = [
  ["alice", "bob", "joseph"],
  ["bob", "tom", "richard"],
  ["richard", "michelle", "amy"],
  ["joseph", "elaine", "albert"],
  ["albert", "colin", "liam"]
]
```

This array is unsorted but it represents a tree of Managers in a company.
for each item in the array, index 0 is the manager while index 1 & 2 are the subordinates of the manager.
basically, it's a tree that looks like this:

```
              alice
            /       \
         bob         joseph
        /   \         /    \
     tom  richard  elaine  albert
          /   \            /  \
   michelle   amy      colin  liam
```

Our output should match this exactly:

Exact Output Needed:

```
alice
bob joseph
tom richard elaine albert
michelle amy colin liam
```

I have tried this but it's showing only the nodes.

```
array = [
    ["alice", "bob", "joseph"],
    ["bob", "tom", "richard"],
    ["richard", "michelle", "amy"],
    ["joseph", "elaine", "albert"],
    ["albert", "colin", "liam"]
]

new_array = Array.new

def treverse(array,new_array)
    final_array = Array.new
    arr = array.shift
    i = true
    arr.each do |b|
        unless new_array.include?(b)
            
            new_array.push(b)
        end
        array.each do |c|
            if c.include?(b)
                treverse(array, new_array)
            end
        end
    end
    return 
end

treverse(array,new_array)

new_array.each do |p|
    puts p
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it solely on the given array.

I would start by turning the array into an actual tree structure. You could for example have a `Node` class with a `name` (e.g. `"alice"`) and a `left` and `right` attribute, referring to the child nodes:

```
Node = Struct.new(:name, :left, :right)
```

To fill the nodes, we can use a helper hash:

```
nodes = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Node.new(k) }
array.each do |name, left, right|
  nodes[name].left = nodes[left]
  nodes[name].right = nodes[right]
end

root = nodes['alice']
#=> #<struct Node name="alice", left=#<struct Node name="bob" ...>, right=... >
```

Now, to traverse (and print) this tree in a breadth-first manner, we can use something like this:

```
def traverse(node)
  row = [node]
  until row.empty?
    puts row.map(&:name).join(' ')
    row = row.flat_map { |n| [n.left, n.right] }.compact
  end
end

traverse(root)
```

The idea is to construct the topmost "row" which is simply our root node: `[node]`. We then print the row's names and create the follow-up row from the `left` and `right` child-nodes of our current row. We repeat until we run out of nodes, i.e. `row` becomes empty.

Output:

```
alice
bob joseph
tom richard elaine albert
michelle amy colin liam
```

Comment: What if a manager manages three employees or more? Why use this `Node` class rather than doing the BFS directly on the tree as it was presented?

Comment: @Stef I've introduced `Node` to have an actual tree structure. A two-dimensional array is not a tree. Regarding multiple employees: I wanted to keep the code simple. You can easily extend it to have an arbitrary number of child nodes, e.g. `row = row.flat_map(&:child_nodes).compact`